# Cross-compile TSLIB Plugin for Qt5 for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm stuck in getting my environment to work properly, here's my situation:
I'm developing a QtQuick1 application to be used on the Raspberry Pi with an capacitive Adafruit PiTFT Touchscreen on /dev/fb1 which works as expected as QtQuick1 applications do not use OpenGL. Display output on the PiTFT works fine but I can't get the touchscreen to work.

As I discovered by now by searching the Web I will have to use TSLIB for touch input, testing the touch works fine.

What I'm stuck with is how to cross-compile the TSLIB Plugin for Qt.
I cross compiled Qt5 for the Raspberry Pi on an Ubuntu machine which worked fine after some tries and tweaks. How can I now cross-compile TSLIB as plugin for Qt?

I already compiled TSLIB directly on the Raspberry Pi, so TSLIB is working fine with the PiTFT touch on the Raspberry, I'm only missing the tslib plugin for Qt on the Raspberry.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have no idea how to build the plugin after Qt was compiled. Usually you add the -tslib flag to your Qt configure and it is build automatically. You get an error message if there are missing dependencies. So the easiest way would probably be to recompile your Qt.

Comment: I finally re-compiled Qt with tslib, the plugin seems to be there now. Nevertheless it's not working properly with my QtQuick1 application, the touch input is not properly recognized.

Answer (score 0):

If you use tslib 1.3, you can simply run `ts_uinput -d` (-d starts it as a daemon) and you have a new input device in `/dev` which provides the filtered touch data. No need for a Qt plugin. Simply point your input event environment to it.